# How to get all tag element named in "href--2RDqa"?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all tag element named in href--2RDqa.

[SpnishDict - Definition of 'que'](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/que)

Ideal result would be like:

```
(keh)
conjuction
pronoun
```

but my current code only catch single result for 'part of speech'.

search result of `que`:

```
(keh)
conjuction
```

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/"
search_keyword = input("input the keyword : ")
url = base_url + search_keyword
spanishdict_r = requests.get(url)
spanishdict_soup = BeautifulSoup(spanishdict_r.text, 'html.parser')

# Phonetic Alphabet
print(spanishdict_soup.find("span", {"id": "dictionary-link-es"}).text)
# Part of Speech
print(spanishdict_soup.find("a", {"class": "href--2RDqa"}).text)
# Meaning
```

I have tried to rename `soup.find` to `soup.findAll` in `#Part of Speech` part, but I got an AttributeError.

> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're
>   probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you
>   call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Please help!
Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this. It’s a basic “How to” web scraping question, of which there are already far too many on here. It’s extremely unlikely that it could ever benefit future readers.

Comment: @AMC It seems like my question is bothering you. Now I'm worried about "no place to ask basic how to question". I still have many question to ask. But I will try something by myself before I ask something.

Comment: I didn’t say there was nowhere to ask these kinds of questions, just that, in my option, this isn’t the place. These web scraping questions are so incredibly specific that they can essentially never be useful to anyone else, no?

Comment: @AMC OK, then you can tell me where to ask these kind of question.

Comment: The learningprogramming subreddit might take these sorts of questions? I think what’s far more important than getting answers to a bunch of specific questions is learning to solve the broader category/class/type of issue.

Comment: @AMC Thanks for your advice. I have posted new question on the Reddit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205624/discussion-between-amc-and-peters7).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you use `soup.findAll` (better to use `soup.find_all` as it's in snake_case), you are returned with a `ResultSet`, which is basically like a list. The error helpfully points that out. Therefore, to extract the text, you'll need to iterate over every element of the list.

Also, given that you can have multiple tags for the same part of speech, you can convert the resulting list into a set based on the .text tag to remove duplicates:

```py
part_of_speech = set([x.text for x in spanishdict_soup.find_all("a", {"class": "href--2RDqa"})])

for part in part_of_speech:
    print(part)
```

Additionally, as was asked by the OP, to preserve the order, you could use a **python3.7 and higher** `dict`, which will act as a pseudo-set:

```py
part_of_speech = dict.fromkeys([x.text for x in spanishdict_soup.find_all("a", {"class": "href--2RDqa"})]).keys()

for part in part_of_speech:
    print(part)
```

or, If you're using a version of python **below 3.7**, then `from collections import OrderedDict`, and using that instead of `dict` should also accomplish the job.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to get result as conjunction pronoun? not conjunction
pronoun pronoun conjunction

Comment: @Peters7 Please check if it works now. I've modified the code so it removes duplicates.

Comment: It works, but can I get result in order? like conjuction comes first in website.

Comment: @Peters7 It now conforms to order as well

Comment: I'm using python 3.8.0 and I added 'from collections import OrderedDict' on the top. It works perfectly fine. I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the `.find()` method and the `.findAll()` method is that the first one returns a `bs4.element.Tag` object type while the latter returns a `bs4.element.ResultSet`. Each element of your `bs4.element.ResultSet` is a `bs4.element.Tag`. Thus, you need to iterate over it:

```
[element.text for element in spanishdict_soup.findAll("a", {"class": "href--2RDqa"})]
```

which renders

```
['conjunction', 'pronoun', 'pronoun', 'conjunction']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried ->   print[element.text for element in spanishdict_soup.findAll("a", {"class": "href--2RDqa"})]   But I got a SyntaxError.

Comment: you have to put parenthesis `print(...)`

Comment: Oh, I missed it. Thanks. How to only get result as conjuction, pronoun?